# Create and Open PDF Kendo UI for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a button and div with some contents. Now if i click the button, then i need to open the content of the div as pdf in new browser window. I have used already Kendo.Drawing , but it only saves as pdf. I want to create a pdf from div content and then open the created pdf in a new window from a button click.

```
 $("#Printbutton").on("click", null, function () {        
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#divContent"))
           .then(function (group) {
               // Render the result as a PDF file
               return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                   paperSize: "auto",
                   margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
               });
           })
           .done(function (data) {
              // Save the PDF file
               kendo.saveAs({
                   dataURI: data,
                   fileName: "Sample.pdf",                  
                   proxyURL: "@Url.Action("Pdf_Export_Save","Home")"
               });
           });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Kendo does not have a function to open the pdf, but you can try using window.open, update your code:

```
.done(function (data) {
   // Open the PDF file
   window.open(data,'_blank','fullscreen=yes');
});
```